# Tarantool doesn't work on Ubuntu 16 (libbfd-2.26-system.so: cannot open shared object file)

Tags: tarantool

I installed Tarantool 1.7 on Ubuntu 16 as instructed https://tarantool.org/download.html 
The installation was successful, but when i run tarantool it fails with error:

**tarantool: error while loading shared libraries: libbfd-2.26-system.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check 'binutils' has been installed, if not:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y binutils
```

Check version:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbfd*
```

if you see:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbfd-2.26.1-system.so
```

then you need:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
$ sudo ln -s libbfd-2.26.1-system.so libbfd-2.26-system.so
```